# Is there a way to perform a comparison while maintaining a fluent pipeline syntax?

Tags: f#

Is there a way to perform a comparison while maintaining a fluent pipeline syntax?

For example, I would like to do this:

```
(positions , source) ||> jump target
                      |> List.length = positions.Length || 
                                       positions.Length - 1
```

But instead, feel like I have to do this:

```
let updatedPositions = (positions , source) ||> jump target
// Return result
updatedPositions |> List.length = positions.Length       || 
updatedPositions |> List.length = positions.Length - 1
```

**Appendix:**

```
[<Property(QuietOnSuccess = true, MaxTest=1000)>]
let ``Attempted checker jump results in zero or one distinct checkers removed`` () =

    // Setup
    gen {
        let! source =          Arb.generate<Piece>
        let! target =          Arb.generate<Piece>
        let! otherPositions =  Arb.generate<Space list>
        let! positions =       Occupied source :: Occupied target
                                               :: otherPositions 
                                               |> Gen.shuffle

        return source , target, positions |> Seq.distinct
                                          |> Seq.toList }
    |> Arb.fromGen

    // Test
    |> Prop.forAll 
    <| fun (source , target, positions) -> 
        (positions , source) ||> jump target
                              |> List.length = positions.Length ||
                                 List.length = positions.Length - 1 // Wish I could do this...
```

Comment: What's wrong with the rather obvious `|> fun l -> l.Length = positions.Length || l.Length = positions.Length - 1`?

Comment: Great solution! Can you post this as the answer so that I can give you credit?

Comment: It doesn't really seem like an 'answer' to me, as you're already using lambdas in your pipeline, so this code doesn't seem to contribute any new concept...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution that @ildjarn posted in the comment is the answer to your question.

However, I would personally not go that way. Piping is useful when you are performing a series of transformations on something that captures "main data of your code". This is nicely captured by the fact that pipeline has one input and one output:

```
let output = 
  input 
  |> firstTransformation
  |> secondTransformation
```

Pipe can be used in many other scenarios (after all, it is just an operator), but I think using it in other scenarios does not make F# code more readable. The nice thing about using pipe only for "main data" is that a quick glance at your code reveals where the important operations are.

This is also partly why I'm not very keen on `||>` - it helps with type inference for `fold` but otherwise, it gives a false impression that a function has one "main input" when it, in fact, needs multiple equally important inputs. So in your example, I would write:

```
let updatedPositions = jump target positions source
updatedPositions.Length = positions.Length || 
  updatedPositions.Length = positions.Length - 1
```

I think this better corresponds to the logic behind the code - pass two things to `jump` and check two properties aboutu the result - than the following pipeline version:

```
(positions, source) 
||> jump target
|> fun updatedPositions -> 
     updatedPositions.Length = positions.Length ||
     updatedPositions.Length = positions.Length - 1
```

The version with `let` is shorter and more straightforward. When reading the second one, you have to unpack quite a lot to figure out what is going on.

Comment: No reason to apologize :-). I think it is very much a matter of style or personal preferences. I just thought I'd write an answer describing how I would write the code (with some more reasoning behind that!)

Answer (score 1):

For the code golf answer, if you want to avoid explicit lambda functions:

If you define the `flip` operator from Haskell `let inline flip f a b = f b a` then you can do `|> List.length |> flip List.contains [positions.Length; positions.Length - 1]`.

You could make it even fancier by defining it as an actual operator, so that it looks like a placeholder:  `let inline (--) f a b = f b a` then you can do `|> List.length |> (List.contains -- [positions.Length; positions.Length - 1])`

Or you could simplify it by using https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Core.Fluent, and it just becomes `|> List.length |> [positions.Length; positions.Length - 1].contains`

I'd not do any of these for production code though.

Comment: `|> List.length |> flip List.contains [positions.Length; positions.Length - 1]` is _exactly_ what I would do for production code, except it would be an array instead of list and `flip` would come from FSharpx. I don't see anything inherently wrong with it at all.